# why different variables within RSpec?

Tags: rspec2, rspec-rails

What is the difference between using a local variable, an instance variable, and one created with the 'let' method inside RSpec tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `let` is the best choice if you need to reuse the variable, otherwise a local variable may make more sense. But you can decide for yourself given the differences:

#### Local variable

Only accessible from within one test, i.e. it cannot be reused.

#### Instance variable

Accessible from all tests within the example group. Assigned and evaluated on every test run in example group.

#### Let

Accessible from all tests within the example group. Lazily evaluated so it is only created (and the code to create it) when it is actually used in a test.

A `let` may still make sense instead of a local variable if the variable logically belongs to a `context` or `describe` block rather than an individual test—but that's preference based on test structure.